# Order .NET objects by reference, not value

Tags: .net, comparison, reference

How can I order (compare) .NET objects by reference?  I would use this to efficiently determine if two .NET collections contain the same instances (by reference, not value).

Another way of phrasing this question might be to ask for an implementation of `IComparer` which uses reference comparison rather than value comparison.

*Note in Java I'd use `System.identityHashCode()`.*

Comment: "order by" reference? Two references can only be "equal" or "unequal", not "higher/lower".

Comment: I would expect the runtime to be able to provide me with an arbitrary (but fixed) ordering on references.

If I could sort both collections by this comparator, then I could more efficiently verify if the collections contain exactly the same object instances.

Comment: It isn't efficient, it requires O(nlog(n)) time and O(n) storage.  Finding duplicates only requires O(n) time and storage.

Comment: Have you profiled your application and determined that this is a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Do you mean, you can find duplicates in O(n) "typical" time with a hashtable?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Object.ReferenceEquals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Note that comparing [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) using the `==` operator also does what you want, unless the equality operator is overridden in these types.

**EDIT:** `System.Object` has [GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx), that works the same way as Java's `hashCode()`. Its behavior might be similar enough to `identityHashCode()` to suit your needs, but I fail to understand how comparing references or hash codes would be representative of the actual value of your objects.

Comment: I want comparison, not equality checking.

Comment: @pauldoo: Can you elaborate what you want with an example?

Comment: I have two instances of `ICollection<Object>`.  I wish to know if both instances contain exactly the same set of objects (by reference equality).

Comment: If I use only `Object.ReferenceEquals()` then this would be an O(N^2) problem.  So, to make this more efficient I could sort both collections by some reference compare function, then use pairwise `Object.ReferenceEquals()` to get runtime down to O(N*log(N)) or so.

Comment: I don't care about the values of the objects, that's the whole point.  I want to know if I have exactly the same collection of instances (ignoring order).

Comment: That's quite an unusual requirement :) `GetHashCode()` should do the trick, then.

Comment: `GetHashCode()` may have been overridden in the objects I'm given, but I guess in most cases this should at least allow me to use pairwise `ReferenceEquals()` on a narrower set of objects.

Comment: I've got a better algo for you: check that collections are of the same size, then stuff all objects from first collection into a dictionary, and then run over second collection and check that all objects are in the dictionary. linear! :) this assumes no dups, if you have dups then you need to keep count in the dictionary.

Comment: The dictionary would use value comparison, not reference comparison as I want.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi C#'s Object.GetHashCode() is the same as Java's Object.hashCode(), both are virtual methods, i.e. can be overridden ->  returned value can change during runtime. System.identityHashCode() otoh is a static function that does NOT return the passed in object's .hashCode(), check the docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object). In other words, your statement directly after EDIT: is wrong and needs correction.

Comment: @Eugene, you're right, answer updated accordingly. Thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Meanwhile I found .net's equivalent of identiyHashCode, check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125710/order-net-objects-by-reference-not-value/9833016#9833016 Not exactly sure what the OP is trying to do, but, fwiw, I found myself in a similar situation long time ago. Maybe it is related to managing cached objects or interning or similar, not sure. In any event, in Java you have IdentityHashMap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) that will do the trick. Not sure an equivalent exists in the .net libs.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a solution to your actual problem using LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> items = new List<Foo>(){ new Foo(), new Foo() };
IEnumerable<Foo> otheritems = items;

bool identical = items.Intersect(otheritems).ToArray().Count() == items.Count();
```

This works by comparing references, unless the `Equals` method is overridden in type `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't literally order .NET objects by reference... apparently you can't even use "unsafe" code to convert a reference to an integer:

```
unsafe int ReferenceToInt(object o)
{
    // Error: cannot declare a pointer to a managed type.
    fixed (object* ptr = o)
        return (int)ptr;
}
```

This wouldn't be a good idea anyway, since a compacting garbage collection could change not only the address of every object, but the relative order between objects. Even if the GC didn't change relative order, the GC can run at any time, which would make ordering by reference very dangerous.

The default implementation of `GetHashCode()` returns some kind of object ID that you can use instead. And, as Frédéric mentioned, you can use Object.ReferenceEquals() to confirm that two references are the same.

Finally, in most cases you should just use Dictionary, HashSet or LINQ, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

.net's equivalent of Java's [System.identityHashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) is 
[RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx)